# How to define a reusable type for any child class with different basecalss in Typescript

Tags: typescript, inheritance, types, parent-child

I have an object which return classes like

```
export const ClassMap: INTERFACE = {
    create: CreateClass,
    update: UpdateClass,
    response: ResponseClass,
    export: ExportClass,
};
```

each of the classes has different base classes like `BaseCreate`, `BaseUpdate`, `BaseResponse`, `BaseExport`
I want to specify a interface as return type for my `classMap` object with generics? how to define it?
I tried this way

```
type BaseClass<B, T extends B> = T & { new (): T & B };
interface MAP<Create, Update, Response, Export> {
    create: BaseClass<BaseCreate, Create>;
    update: BaseClass<BaseUpdate, Update>;
    response: BaseClass<BaseResponse, Response>;
    export: BaseClass<BaseExport, Export>;
}
```

but it showing that some of the props are missing?
is there any better solution?`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and all you want is `class Create extends BaseCreate`, all you need is

```
interface MAP<Create extends typeof BaseCreate> {
  //                         ^ implied (class BaseCreate) & (new()=>BaseCreate)
  create: Create
  // same for ither 3
}
```

Comment: hi when i used 'dto: typeof Dto' like that i am getting type errors like some of the properties are doesnt exist? is there any work around?